# Unable to install Django in my mac - |setup.py egg_info" failes with 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I tried to install Django using `sudo pip install Django` command. It has downloaded but got stuck to error - `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1`.

Terminal

[image]

I've installed `Python 3.6.3`, but `pip` still pointing to `Python 2.7`, is above issue occurs because of pip not pointing to `python 3.6.3`?

Terminal

[image]

Comment: create a virtualenv with python 3.6 and then run pip inside that

Comment: use anaconda .. nothing binding to OS

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
python3.6 -m pip install
```

But it would be better if you create virtualenv for python 3.6 and then install packages in it

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned you would be better installing using a virtual environment.

Have a look at [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/)  it simplifies the whole process of managing virtual environments.

```
pipenv --python 3.6 install django
```

The above command would create a virtual environment using python 3.6 and install django